# How to avoid pip install global packages accidentally?

Tags: pip

Sometimes I forget to activate the virtual environment before executing the `pip install` command, which causes a bunch of useless global pip packages. Some of them are not able to be uninstalled directly using pip (dateutils issue). 
I wonder how I can avoid such accidents? 
Can I disable pip for non-root users and only permit `sudo pip`?

Comment: As far as I know, pip will install to your home directory if you didn't run `sudo`.  So, you should be able to delete what you've accidentally installed.  But something you could do that addresses your question is create an alias in .bash_aliases so that `pip` maps to something (i.e., an echo command that laughs at you :-) ).  What I don't know is if you activate a virtual environment, whether the path to its `pip` is guaranteed to precede the alias.  If this doesn't work, you can add a `pip` executable file and a path leading to it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.  FWIW, I had `sudo` access on a (shared) server and I sometimes stupidly do a `sudo reboot` on it instead of the (unshared) desktop I'm on.  (i.e., I type it so quickly that I didn't think carefully...)  To "solve" this, I aliased "sudo" to give me a message on the server.  It wasn't an elegant solution, but it solved my problem.

Comment: this is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354852/how-to-make-sure-you-call-pip-only-in-virtualenv)ed over on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

I am not as good at writing bash scripts but you can replace the pip command with an alias in your `bashrc` with this script

```
if [[ $(python -c 'import sys; print (sys.real_prefix)' 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
 /path/to/actual/pip/executable install $1;
else
 echo "not in a virtual env";
fi
```

This script solve your problem. If there is anyone who can find an issue in the script or improve it, please do.